# Content Negotiation in Spring by AbstractCachingViewResolver order attribute uses

Tags: spring-mvc

p:order="1" what does have it means to my application.
Is is any kind of priority of loading of beans classes in my application.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="order" value="2" />
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultHandler">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="ajaxViewResolver" class="org.springframework.js.ajax.AjaxUrlBasedViewResolver" p:order="1">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.js.ajax.tiles3.AjaxTilesView"/>
</bean>
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" p:order="2">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
</bean>
```

in second code **`p:order="1"`** is the order of deployment/loading beans in container

Comment: I have found out Something Useful may be the Potential Answer
http://pablo.anecico.com/cgblog/10/15/Render-fragments-with-Spring-MVC-Tiles-and-Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found It Helpful so sharing it.The order is an order of resolving the views by Spring framework.
Went to a blog and a documentation.

1. [A spring Blog](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/web-flow/55879-chaining-view-resolvers-internalresourceviewresolver-ajaxurlbase-dviewresolver-prob)
2. [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html)

When chaining ViewResolvers, a UrlBasedViewResolver always needs
to be last, as it will attempt to resolve any view name, no matter whether
the underlying resource actually exists.